# How to access a method from another class without using extends keyword?

Tags: java, oop, methods

I have a main class followed by two sub classes.

As below

```
public class Guitar  {

   public static void main(String argd[]) {
       Artist output = new Artist();
       output.perfomance();
   }
}

  class Artist  {
    String Name;
    void perfomance () {

    }

  }

  class Album {

  }
```

Is it possible to call method performance from Artist class and use it in Album class without extends keyword?

Comment: There are several ways, depends on what you actually want to achieve conceptually.

Comment: @kryger . Lets say that i have local variables that method ?

Comment: @procrastinator . i created an method and called the method from artist class  .  `void perfomance () {
     Artist.perfomance();} ` . but this is not giving the result

Comment: @procrastinator  .. its fine now .. thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use composition instead of inheritance.

If Album extends Artist then you are suggesting the and Album IS-A Artist.
However if an Album has an Artist as a member then Album HAS-A Artist.

See [IS-A vs HAS-A](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php)

So one approach might be to do

```
class Album {
  Artist artist;

  Album(Artist artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
  }

  void playLive() {
    artist.performance();
  }
}
```

So to call you might do

```
public class Guitar  {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Artist prince = new Artist();
     Album purpleRain = new Album(prince);
     purpleRain.playLive();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about using constructor here, so just to make my understanding clear: Won't it be easier and accessible without constructor as well?

Comment: If it is the case that there cannot be an album with out an artist then this ensures you must supply an artist when an album is instantiated.

If you did not supply an artist before the `playLive()` method was called then you would get a null pointer exception.

If you were to instantiate the Artist inside the Album class then you would still need to figure out what Artist to use. 

An alternative is to pass the artist into the playLive method is different artists can play the same album

`void playLive(Artist artist)`

It all depends on what business logic you are trying to model.

Comment: Oh yes. Makes sense now. :)

Comment: @Spangen ..  Here. in main method how many objects i need to create to call each them

Comment: @coffemug
I'll amend my answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**: [Use composition](https://www.journaldev.com/1325/composition-in-java-example)

Pass Artist object from constractor

```
class Album {
  Artist artist;

  Album(Artist artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
  }

  void doSothing() {
    artist.performance();
  }
}
```

Set Artist object with set Method

```
class Album {
      Artist artist;
      void setArtist(Artist artist){ 
         this.artist = artist;
       }
      void doSothing(Artist artist) {
        artist.performance();
      }
    }
```

Pass Artist object from method

```
class Album {
      Artist artist;

      void doSothing(Artist artist) {
        artist.performance();
      }
    }
```

**Method 2**: Make function perfomance  [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java)

```
 public class Artist  {
    String Name;
    static void perfomance () {
    }
  }
  class Album {
   void doSothing() {
     Artist.performance();
   }
  }
```

Comment: i like the answer but now i am giving spangen as best answer .. thanks for yours answer